# Is it possible set the excell cells format although the cells have some value?

Tags: phpexcel

I'm trying to get a solution, but there's nobody on Internet with this problem I guess.
I'm using a lot of PHPExcel scripts, but now I need to set the size of the cells, despite the information its have. For example I would need all the cells with the same format and it information inside hide. 
I attach a screenshot, I would need just the cells with a small size and all of it with the same format but I can't make it. 
At the image I need the cells with the red height for example, but one of it have more information than the others, and make all of it with a big height.

Thank you so much,

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.... do you just want row  to be a fixed height? Or do you want to hide the row so that it can't be seen?

Comment: I want a fixed height despite the cell has information. I don't want the cell get higher height if it has information,

Comment: So what's the problem with `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('5')->setRowHeight(25.5);` to set the height of row 5 to 25.5pt as described in the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-a-rows-height)?

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried this but in some moments don't recognize me the setRowHeight , now it works fine to me!
Should I delete this post?